# Reporting Services 2005 Hide Columns Only in Certain Table Groups (eliminate white space)

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a report (rdlc) that has a data set that has row grouping based upon certain field values.
It is set up to appear as separate tables for each grouping.
I now have a requirement to display a column for only one of these groupings.
For example, if value = a then show a column in the grouped table.
If value <> a then do not display this column.
I have tried several visibility techniques but cannot get the column to show in only one grouping.
The closest I got was to show the column in the required grouping, but it left white space for the column within the other tables.

Has anyone successfully tried anything similar?

Thanks for any and all assistance!!!

Comment: "Row Grouping" and "Separate tables" for each group don't seem compatible, so I'm not sure what you mean. I suspect you don't really have separate tables? Can you provide screenshots of what you have and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: they are one table. However, using extra empty rows, without borders, I have created the appearance of separate tables.  It appears the only solution will be actual separate tables with data filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table in SSRS ( and many other systems) must have the same columns for every row, and the same rows for every column. You can merge some of these, but that won't accomplish what you want: changing the number of columns for only some rows of the table.

I would separate this into multiple tables. Use the filters property of the different tables(tablixes) to filter each table to only display the appropriate rows if you would like to keep your current dataset.

Comment: that's what I found, but was hoping for a different answer. Thanks!